# Why do sweep accounts not inflate prices at the end of the business day?

Tags: banking, investment, reserve-requirement-ratio

From [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sweepaccount.asp), sweep accounts are defined as

> a bank or brokerage account that automatically transfers amounts that
> exceed a certain level into a higher interest-earning investment
> option at the close of each business day.

Apparently, these are common enough to significantly reduce the overnight reserves banks are required to hold. (See the second table [here](https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/epr/02v08n1/0205benn/0205benn.html).) At the end of every business day, a lot of money is being transferred from checking and brokerage accounts into investments. Why don't the prices of investments go up at the end of each business day and down at the start of the next business day?

Of course, if the investments did follow these cycles, investors could take advantage of the opportunity by selling investments at the end of the business day and buying them back at the start of the next business day. Who are these investors? Do they hold cash overnight?